# Lamp installation not working via command line

Tags: command-line, linux-mint

I just went to this site: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486 and tried to follow the tutorial on how to install mint. The appache installation worked. However, when I paste the following code to install php, it does not work

sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5

This is what is displays after I type the command:

```
sidney-the-programmer sidney # sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate
```

Is there another? Anything wrong from my side?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @srael.zinc. Please check edited question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: download it again! File missing i guess